# How to access whole document from active window in gedit

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygtk, pygobject, gedit

I want to access the whole document from the current window of the gedit. Is there any function of the doc object class that returns the whole document from the active window.

when I use dir on the doc I get 2 3 functions which may return the document from the active window but when I try to access those functions they raise an error

```
doc = self.window.get_active_document()
qdata = doc.get_qdata()
file = doc.get_file()
doc.set_text(str(qdata))
```

Error log

```
raise RuntimeError('Data access methods are unsupported. '
RuntimeError: Data access methods are unsupported. Use normal Python attributes instead
```

Comment: Did you try to use python attributes?

Comment: @elya5 I did not get the whole point of accessing python attributes.

Comment: Maybe there are some quirks in the implementation and something like `doc.qdata` works?